# javascript grabbing span tag with both class and id

Tags: javascript

I have a span tag

```
<span class="vi-is1-prcp" id="v4-25">US $99.00</span>
```

I would like to grab it using pure javascript. JQuery or any other library is not allowed. Is that possible?

I recon that

```
getElementById('v4-25')
```

won't work since I have to specify class, too, correct?

Thank you,

So,

```
<div id="listprice">asdasdasdasdasd</div>
var string = document.getElementById('v4-25');
document.getElementById('listprice').innerHTML = string;
```

should print value of 'v4-25' in 'listpirce' ?

H

Comment: getElementById looks only at the id and since id values must be unique in the page, what you have proposed should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, ids are unique.  You can't have more than one.  therefore, when you select element by id, you can only bring back one element (this is good).

Secondly, after you get an element, you have to do something with it. `var string = document.getElementById('v4-25');` only gets you the element, but it looks like you want `var string = document.getElementById('v4-25').innerHTML;` for the price.  If you do want the id instead you can do `var string = document.getElementById('v4-25').id;` but because that just returns "v4-25" it's a bit redundant.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementById` will work just fine.  Just make sure you're running it after the page has loaded.

Comment: So,

<div id="listprice">asdasdasdasdasd</div>
var string = document.getElementById('v4-25');
document.getElementById('listprice').innerHTML = string;

should print value of 'v4-25' in 'listpirce' ?

Comment: Maybe you're abbreviating the code; no, that doesn't make sense.  If you have both a div with the ID `listprice` and `v4-25` in the page, then you can set the innerHTML of `listprice` to that of `v4-25` by doing this: `document.getElementById('listprice').innerHTML = document.getElementById('v4-25').innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to add a class. Run the script after that dom element is loaded like this.

```
<span class="vi-is1-prcp" id="v4-25">US $99.00</span>
<script>
    var elm = document.getElementById('v4-25');
</script>
```